# FabricJs image not loading when imported by JSON

Tags: json, image, loading, fabricjs

Im trying to load some images onto the canvas with fabricjs. They have been exported by fabricjs already before using **JSON.stringify(canvas);**.

This is the code I use to import the JSON object:

```
var canvas = this.__canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
var json2 = {"objects":[{"type":"image","originX":"left","originY":"top","left":0,"top":0,"width":257,"height":258,"fill":"rgb(0,0,0)","stroke":null,"strokeWidth":1,"strokeDashArray":null,"strokeLineCap":"butt","strokeLineJoin":"miter","strokeMiterLimit":10,"scaleX":1,"scaleY":1,"angle":0,"flipX":false,"flipY":false,"opacity":1,"shadow":null,"visible":true,"clipTo":null,"backgroundColor":"","fillRule":"nonzero","globalCompositeOperation":"source-over","src":"http://fabricjs.com/article_assets/9.png","filters":[],"crossOrigin":"","alignX":"none","alignY":"none","meetOrSlice":"meet"}],"background":""};

canvas.loadFromJSON(json2, canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));
```

When I do the same with a rect object it gets loaded fine. Only the images are not getting loaded. I added an example fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/waaqk9tr/5/

What could be wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server fabricjs.com, is not allowing cross-origin requests. If you look in your browser's network inspector or console, you will see the error:

```
[Error] Cross-origin image load denied by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy.
    fromObject (fabric.min.js, line 5)
    (anonymous function) (fabric.min.js, line 1)
    forEach
    enlivenObjects (fabric.min.js, line 1)
    _enlivenObjects (fabric.min.js, line 3)
    loadFromJSON (fabric.min.js, line 3)
    (anonymous function) (_display, line 39)
    j (jquery.min.js, line 2)
    add (jquery.min.js, line 2)
    ready (jquery.min.js, line 2)
    onload (_display, line 26)
```

Probably, you're just playing around and you don't really need to load an image from fabricjs.com. If you did, then you'd have to employ a work-around. You see, your browser sends an Origin header, with the domain of the site running your javascript (jsfiddle.net in this case), and you cannot modify that header. Then the server, fabricjs.com, sees the header and rejects the request.

A workaround would be to proxy the image request through a server. Or for kicks, you might try opening, http://fabricjs.com/article_assets/9.png, in a separate browser tab, to put in in your browser's HTTP cache, and then run the fiddle again, which causes the image to load from cache. This worked for me, and I saw the little pug dog in the canvas, but it's not a legit solution.